# Couldn't get json_encode($resu) in android onPostExecute(String res)

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to connect my android app with backend MySQL and I used php as server side language, but the problem is as I am echoing `$res` array from php, it is not accessed in Android `onPoseExecute(String res)`.

I have tried the same code in other apps and it's working  perfectly fine there.. but this code is not showing proper response, neither the error in creating Json object.

My username is defined in `OnCrate()` of android code.

Here is my php Code:

```
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "SWR");

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return $str;
}   

$empID = strtoupper(clean($_POST['username']));
$resu = array();
$resu["status"] = true;
$sql3="insert into t_booked_hall values ('','$empID','','','','','','1','','','0','','0','','','','','','','','0','','','0','','')";    
$result3 = mysqli_query($con,$sql3);    
echo json_encode($resu);
```

Android Code:

```
public class SigninActivity  extends AsyncTask<String, Void , String>{
    protected void onPreExecute(){}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try{
            link="https://haripriyag2362.000webhostapp.com/login_php.php";
            String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                    URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");

            URL url = new URL(link);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write( data );
            wr.flush();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    //final context context = this;
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        try{
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);

            if(jObj.getBoolean("status")) {
                 Toast.makeText(emp_home.this,"Invalid Succesful..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(emp_home.this,"Invalid Login ! Try Again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }catch (JSONException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing `break;` in `while` loop in `doInBackground` method

Comment: Yes. You are reading one line now only.

Comment: `it is not accessed in Android onPoseExecute(String res)..` What do you mean by that? You could have told us what String res contained.

Comment: `JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);` You should not do that blindly as there is also a statement `return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());`. So first check if res starts with "Exception:".

Comment: Thank you Sir, @greenapps Removing, break in while loop solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You must just remove break; in while loop

You Can Use getJSONfromURL(url) func to Get Array Response From Server

```
 public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    // Download JSON data from URL
    try {
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);



        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
        //Here Connection TimeOut excepion
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    // Convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    try {

        jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }

    return jArray;
}
```

Comment: @chandu is that help?